# ItemTouchHelper How to change the minimun distance neede to start swiping?

Tags: kotlin, swipe

I want to use ItemTouchHelperCallback to swipe the rows, but I want to change the distance needed to trigger the swipe.

Any Ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but look on the [**getSwipeTreshold**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback#getSwipeThreshold(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder)) method.

> Returns the fraction that the user should move the View to be considered as swiped. The fraction is calculated with respect to RecyclerView's bounds.

Just change the returning value.

Or, if you talking about swipe action, there is a method [**getSwipeEscapeVelocity**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback#getSwipeEscapeVelocity(float))

> Defines the minimum velocity which will be considered as a swipe action by the user.